# How to get artifact from maven repository without maven?

Tags: maven, maven-3

First, I am not a maven user.  I need this library: https://github.com/ansell/JenaSesame but only the source code is available.  The readme shows this information:

```
Repository

http://openjena.org/repo-dev

Group:      org.openjena 
Artifact:   jena-sesame
```

But when I browse to that location I get a 404.  How can I grab that artifact from that repository?  I'm willing to install maven if I have to to get it; I just need the compiled library jars.

I have already searched the maven central repository at http://search.maven.org , and it is not there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any publicly-accessible repository should be viewable in a browser, and as such you should be able to download any JAR file contained within. The URL you've listed, <strike>openjena.org/repo-dev</strike> <sub>[1]</sub>, looks more like a development repository.  There are plenty of repositories around the world that are internal repositories, so this looks like one that hasn't been set up for public consumption.

It looks like they have binary releases available for download here: http://www.apache.org/dist/jena/  Have you looked there for what you're after?

<sub>[1]: Now a spam domain - visit https://jena.apache.org/ instead.</sub>

Comment: Thanks but that's for the Jena library.  This particular library that I need is a separate one whose purpose is to integrate Jena with Sesame

Comment: Hmm, bugger.  Well, as Trever said, if it's not available as a binary, you'll have to check the source out and build it yourself.  It might be a good excuse to give Maven a try.  I did look at the repository in which this maven project deploys (http://maven.metadata.net/artifactory/webapp) but I couldn't see the artifacts it is building.  Sorry

Comment: Okay thanks... so at least you answered the question, which is that any  publicly-accessible repository should be viewable in a browser.